# autossh not working and run without any error message

Tags: ssh

I have no problem when running this command on ssh , but in autossh its not working.
the list of command i have done till now :

```
1- ssh-keygen -t rsa
2- cp id_rsa.pub /home/sshUser/.ssh/authorized_keys2/
3- cp id_rsa /home/sshUser/.ssh/authorized_keys2/
4- autossh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 sshUser@10.100.20.25
```

and after the last line nothing happen.
ssh still done and ive check it with : "sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\'"
but if i use ssh instead of autossh it works.

Comment: I get this problem with Cygwin in 2023. I've never seen it before on Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux Mint 17 (~Ubuntu 14.04), I need to run `autossh` as `sudo` in order to have it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a very similar problem: `autossh` would not react, but show the help text.

The solution is to add the monitoring port, i.e. the `-M <port>` parameter. If you set `-M 0` monitoring will be disabled.

Unfortunately until the current Version `1.40`, the help shows the `-M` parameter as optional. This is an [known problem](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/11471#issuecomment-5026458).

Comment: Very helpful, this was my first time using autossh and I was trying to run  the command as is, without adding -M. Your answer got it working! I was puzzled by the lack of errors output.

Comment: I ran into this issue when moving from ubuntu to arch.